# axios GET Request constantly running

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on my React application and noticed an error. When I console log the code below, the GET request from my Express back end, the console log runs without stopping.

#### api-helper.js (REACT)

```
export const getAllPages = async () => {
  getToken();
  const resp = await api.get(`pages/`);
  console.log('><><><><><><><>< return getAllPages response ><><><><><><><><',resp) // 
  const parsedResponse = resp.data.map((page) => ({
    ...page,
    siteName: page.siteUniqueName?.split("-")[1],
  }));
  return parsedResponse;
};
```

#### pageRouter.js (express)

```
pageRouter.get("/", restrict, async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { user } = req;
    const pages = await Page.findAll({
      where: {
        userId: user.id
      },
      include: [
        { model: Site },
        { model: VisitRecord },
        { model: Lead }
      ]
    });
    res.json(pages);
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
});
```

This would obviously be bad in production if it were making calls on a live database. How do I get this to stop this get running constantly in the background?

**Update**:

This is the code on the dashboard that calls the API where all pages are rendered:

#### Dashboard.jsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getAllPages();
  }, []);
```

#### App.js

```
  getAllUserPages = async () => {
    // console.log('called here1')
    const pages = await getAllPages();
    if (pages) {
      this.setState({
        sites: pages,
      });
    }
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    // console.log('called________')
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser) {
      const preservedSites = await getAllPages();
      this.setState({
        currentUser,
        preservedSites: preservedSites.map((site) => site.siteName),
      });
    } else {
      if (
        !(
          this.props.history.location.pathname.startsWith("/reset/") ||
          this.props.history.location.pathname === "/" ||
          matchPath(this.props.history.location.pathname, {
            path: "/:userId/:siteName",
            exact: false,
            strict: false,
          })
        )
      ) {
        this.props.history.push("/auth");
      }
    }
    const pages = await getAllPages();
    if (pages) {
      this.setState({
        sites: pages,
      });
    }
    const resp = await api.get("/users");
    const users = resp.data;
    this.setState({
      users: users,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sure you aren't caught in a re-render loop in whatever React component is using that service call?  That seems a likely source of the problem.

Comment: Can you add the react code that calls the api?